# Ansible: playbook times out gatherthing facts

Tags: ssh, ansible, debian

So, just getting started with Ansible. I'm trying to run a simple playbook to install Apache2 on a Raspberry Pi, adapted from this [example from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ansible-to-install-and-set-up-apache-on-ubuntu-18-04). I can ping the machine and ssh in without issues. However, the script seems to stall indefinitely at the gathering facts stage. The last bit of output from running the command with the `-vvv` flag is this

```
SSH: EXEC sshpass -d42 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="Nizz0k"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/Nizz0k/.ansible/cp/23ecd22287 192.168.0.45 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~Nizz0k && sleep 0'"'"''
```

So, I can guess that something is sending the script to sleep, but I have no idea why. Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the script sleeping. `sleep 0` is used in every ssh command sent by ansible. If you want to know more about this, see [the comment in ansible source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/action/__init__.py#L1225) and the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/13876). Did you issue a "top" on your Rasperry while this was running ? Which version of python are you using on the target ? If python2, can you make a test with python3 ? What if you disable fact gathering and play an other module ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. No, I didn't issue any stop command to the pi, it's just got raspian lite with ssh enabled. The Pi has python 3, but checking the version it's not linked. I'll fix and re-try